# Websphere Service Log and Log Level what is the relation

Tags: java, websphere

I understand that activity.log(service log) contains JVM log also. Can you please tell me **how we can control the log level in activity.log**. Can it be controlled by log level in "Change log detail levels". I do not want to stop it, rather control the level of log in activity log.

**"Change log detail levels" option in websphere controls JVM logs? means systemout.log and systemerr.log?** That means if we set log level at INFO level in "Change log detail levels", it will log INFO level log in activity.log also? because JVM log are logged in activity.log also. And if I update it to "ERROR" it will update activity.log also.

**What is the best log level in production environment for JVM logs?**

Answer (score 1):

Activity log is binary log, mostly to be used by support. You can only control its location, filename and size. In v8 it is disabled by default. Usually you should not change settings for this log.

Change log detail level controls logging and tracing. FINE, FINER and FINEST setting only goes to the trace.log.

There is no best log level setting for all environments. It depends how much information you need. I'd say the default (*=info) is most commonly used. You could change it to warning, if you have too many, not important, information strings saved to log. Check this [page](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-mp&topic=utrb_loglevel) for explanations of log levels.